# How to change a function based on the length of an input variable

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, function

I have written a function that scans a list of strings by index for regex matches in the current and next two indexes of the list. If a match is found across three indexes, those elements in the list are joined.

```
import re
from nltk.tokenize import MWETokenizer

s = ['Here','be', 'dragons', 'Captain', '23', 'March', '2018', 'and', 'Oct', '22', '2018']
pattern = [r'\d{2}|[a-zA-Z]{3,5}', r'\d{2}|[a-zA-Z]{3,5}', r'\d{4}']

def un_tokenize(pattern, sep, toks):
    tokenizer = MWETokenizer([], separator=sep)
    for i in list(range(0, len(toks)-len(pattern)+1)):
        if bool(re.match(pattern[0], toks[i])) and \
           bool(re.match(pattern[1], toks[i+1])) and \
           bool(re.match(pattern[2], toks[i+2])):

           tup = (toks[i], toks[i+1], toks[i+2])
           tokenizer.add_mwe(tup)
    return tokenizer.tokenize(toks)


print(un_tokenize(pattern, '+', s))
```

which correctly returns

> ['Here', 'be', 'dragons', 'Captain', '23+March+2018', 'and', 'Oct+22+2018']

I want to know,
1) How can I change the if statement to include a variable number of 'and's, so that I can put in a pattern of 2 regexes or 4 regexes etc.?

2) I am sure this is not the most pythonic way of doing this, so I other methods are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use "all()" with "map()" to support arbitrary size pattern list:

```
def un_tokenize(pattern, sep, toks):
    tokenizer = MWETokenizer([], separator=sep)
    for i in list(range(0, len(toks)-len(pattern)+1)):
        if (all(map(re.match, pattern, toks[i:i+len(pattern)]))):
           tup = (toks[i:i+len(pattern)])
           tokenizer.add_mwe(tup)
    return tokenizer.tokenize(toks)
```

Comment: Thankyou, @Elad! I changed the tup line as well to >tup = (toks[i:i+len(pattern)]) and it works!

Comment: updated the answer according to your comment so the answer will be complete